# ShellExecute/Schtasks - WinXP ask password

Tags: delphi, winapi

On Windows 7/8/10 I'm using this command to schedule a task from my executable application:

```
  ShellExecute(0, Nil, 'schtasks',
  PAnsiChar('/create /sc minute /mo 5 /tn "Secure Script" /tr "C:\scripts\sc.vbs"'),
  nil, SW_SHOW);
```

No problem on this Windows versions, but testing on a Windows XP machine, I get the following message:

> The task will be created under current logged-on user name
>   ("IE8WINXP\IEUser"). Please enter the run as password for
>   IE8WINXP\IEUser:

This breaks the automation of the process. Is there anyway to avoid this message, and schedule a task automated, without providing the current user password?

Comment: Isn't there an API for creating scheduled tasks?

Comment: Humm... I dont know about it, because all examples I saw on internet, was using ShellExecute...

Comment: @LessStress I guess you didn't look on MSDN.  [Task Scheduler 1.0 Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @J..., that should be the answer. A simple code paste from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx should do the trick. The code can be translated from C++ with minimum effort.

Comment: @Johan: A more relevant link would be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - it shows creating a new task, while yours shows how to run a task.